# "an item with the same key has already been added" while setting <compilation debug="false"> in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

While compiling my application (ASP.NET, C#), i set **compilation debug="false"** in Web.config
 to improve the performance and published it upon development machine, It was working fine at development machine.

But when i moved the these compiled files to Hosting Server, Application showed me this exception

**an item with the same key has already been added**

Since this was the only change i made, i changed the attribute like **"debug=true"** and system started working fine at hosting machine.

But i don't want to keep debug=true because of performance issues caused by this attribute.

Please share your experience if anybody faced similar situation.

Comment: .NET has  different configuration files which get merged together. It seems KEY(which should be unique) is already  defined in some other config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deleting the debug attribute altogether, the default is false.

You should also check to see if there are any other web.config files present in the parent folders of where you are publishing the web application.  If so are they required?

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I commented the whole compilation tag and it seems like working :-)

Comment: Yeah makes sense, it was probably conflicting with a parent .config file.  Thanks for letting me know.